# react-native-agora Warning 8, Warning 16

Tags: react-native, agora.io

```js
useEffect(() => {
    initEngine();

    return () => {
      engine?.destroy();
    };
  }, []);

  const initEngine = async () => {
    if (engine) return;
    engine = await RtcEngine.createWithContext(new RtcEngineContext(appId));

    addListeners();

    await engine?.enableVideo();
    await engine?.startPreview();
    await engine?.setChannelProfile(ChannelProfile.LiveBroadcasting);
    await engine?.setClientRole(ClientRole.Broadcaster);
}

  const addListeners = () => {
    engine?.addListener('Warning', warningCode => {
      console.info('Warning', warningCode);
    });
    engine?.addListener('Error', errorCode => {
      console.info('Error', errorCode);
    });
    engine?.addListener('JoinChannelSuccess', (channel, uid, elapsed) => {
      console.info('JoinChannelSuccess', channel, uid, elapsed);
      setIsJoined(true);
    });
    engine?.addListener('LeaveChannel', stats => {
      console.info('LeaveChannel', stats);
      setIsJoined(false);
      setRemoteUid([]);
    });
    engine?.addListener('UserJoined', (uid, elapsed) => {
      console.info('UserJoined', uid, elapsed);
      setRemoteUid([...remoteUid, uid]);
    });
    engine?.addListener('UserOffline', (uid, reason) => {
      console.info('UserOffline', uid, reason);
      setRemoteUid(remoteUid.filter(value => value !== uid));
    });
  };
```

This is my code example.

I take Warning 8 and Warning 16.

My camera doesn't come out.

But the other person can see my face.

I don't know how to solve the error code even if I look at it.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @KenWhite I deleted the image. thanks

Comment: That's good, but you should replace the image with the complete error messages in text format. That text is searchable content that could help others in the future find this question.

Comment: @HoJin are you testing on iOS or Android? If iOS, did you add `NSCameraUsageDescription` and `NSMicrophoneUsageDescription` to your `Info.plist` file? Adding that fixed this problem for me...